# How can I add text content to display in the game if the free look camera is too close to player?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: Free look camera in close view but the ui text is out of view and hard to be set]

The problem is that I want to make that when the game start to display a close view scene in the game and some text in front of the player. but since the camera is too close to the player I changed the middlering Height and Radius to make it close and then the ui text should be much lower position but I can't see it in the game view window and then when I'm building the game and running it it's looking different.

I can't see the gameview window as it should be in the build. and if I will move the camera a bit back to see the text then again it will not what I will see in the build later.

I tried to stretch the game view window as much as I can but it's not enough.

This is how it looks like when I'm running the game in the editor :

[image: When running the game in the editor]

And this is how it looks like when running the game from the build exe.
I want the text to be a bit lower but I can't see what I'm doing in the Game View window.

[image: The view when running the build]

The game view is not the same as the build view. so it's hard to set the ui text position size and other stuff.

This is my ui texts I'm using :

[image: The ui text/s]

Any ideas what to do to make it possible to set the ui text easier ?
The problem is with the perspective if this is the word to describe the problem.

Comment: Try to accommodate UI text sizes to different size screens. That way, if a user has a screen size similar to your game view (a bit of a stretch), they can still see the text.

Comment: @Bingostew Still not working. The problem is not how the player see it when running the game but how I see it in the editor in the game view window.  Since the camera is very close to the player there is no room to see the text and then you don't know how much to move it by position size and stuff.  Look at the first and last screenshots the text should be more or less like in the middle screenshot but the middle screenshot is from the build running and the view is in full screen in the editor the game vie is not full screen and it's impossible to see and set the text.

Comment: I am suggesting you to set the UI according to the sizes of the screen in code, for example, `text.minWidth = Screen.width - 20;` If you are setting your texts manually in your inspector, then it would be harder to tell unless you go in full screen during play. Therefore, I don't know a better way to set the UI.